# What should you do if your cat brings Chametz into your house?

Tags: passover, animals, chametz-leaven

Your cat plays outside during the day on Pesach. You see your cat rolling around in the dirt that has Chametz that was deposited by Gentiles walking on the street. The cat also decides to carry a bag of Chametz in its mouth and runs into your house with the bag.

Do you need to brush the cats fur and inspect it for Chametz even if it's not clearly visible?

What should you do with the bag of Chametz if the cat brings it into your house during Yom Tov? Is the Chametz muktzah, so you can't move it? If the cat has eaten the Chametz on its own, have you violated owning Chametz on Pesach, or is this nullified by the fact that you didn't physically own it since you didn't move it, and now it's gone, anyway?

Comment: Just saying, just because your cat brings chametz into your home doesn't mean it belongs to you. At least that's one thing...

Comment: @EzraHoerster why's that? The rambam discusses cleaning chames brought in my rats.

Comment: @ShamanSTK You said - "my rats". I recommend that you get rid of your rats BEFORE you get rid of your chametz. I think that Ramba"m would have made the same recommendation ;-)

Comment: @DanF oops. I'll have to move my rats over to a kitniyos diet.

Comment: @ShamanSTK Yeah that'a true but I wasn't really answering the question anyways. That's why it's in the comments.

Comment: I remember learning (I think in Mishnah Brurah) that there are clear halachot re chametz brought in by animals, including what to do if it is brought in on the chag itself. In general, IIRC, you get rid of it, preferably by burning, but not on chag/shabbat of course. On shabbat/chag you cover it and burn it at the earliest opportunity.